# finding maximal element in c++ map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

We have `C++ map<double, class_name>` `mymap`.
We are given some double `X`.

Task is to find value in mymap associated with the largest key that is less than equal to `X`. If `X` is less than lowest key of `mymap` return some default value declared before.

My approach is iterate through `mymap` and find maximal key that is less than or equal to `X`

```
double max = std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest();

for ( auto ii=mymap.begin(); ii!=mymap.end(); ++ii ) {
  if (
    (*ii).first <= value && 
    (*ii).first > max
  ) {
    max = (*ii).first;
  }
}

if ( max==std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest() )
    return defaultValue;

return colorset.find(max)->second;
```

Is this correct approach?
I am new at c++ map, so I want to know may be there is a better way of implementing this task?

I guess proposed algorithm's complexity is `O(n)`, probably there is a way to find it `O(log n)` or with even better complexity or memory allocation?

Comment: @PP, value means value of map associated with some key k

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`map::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound) to find the smallest element larger than or equal to `X`, check if you've got a `begin()` iterator to decide that the value is smaller than the smallest one in the map, and go back one step to go to the key that's the largest one not exceeding `X`:

```
map<double, class_name>::const_iterator iter = mymap.lower_bound(X);
if (iter->first == X || iter != mymap.begin()) {
    if (iter->first != X) --iter;
    cerr << iter->second << endl;
} else {
    cerr << "<default>" << endl;
}
```

Unlike a plain loop (that iterates all the keys in order) `map::lower_bound` knows about the internal structure of `std::map` an can take advantage of it during the search, resulting in better performance.

[Here is a demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/XK4Ccp)

Comment: specifically: `O(log N)` complexity for the member `lower_bound` vs `O(N)` for the generic `std::find`

Comment: Is there const type for lower_bound function? Because my function is declared as const

Comment: @ dasblinkenlight, in general you answered for question. But, it is not correct algorithm, may be you wanted to use upper_bound function?

Comment: @ dasblinkenlight, this again is not correct because if I give X,which is more than all elements of mymap function returns default value

Comment: @NurlanKenzhebekov Did you try this last edit of 35 minutes ago? My demo [shows](http://ideone.com/XK4Ccp) that when you give a large number, it gives you the last item from the map. **EDIT** Oops, I missed one change that I made in the demo but not in the answer: replace `upper_bound` with `lower_bound` again.